# Camel: PollEnrich generating a lot of Timed Waiting threads

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

I have this camel route

```
    from("file:{{PATH_INPUT}}?charset=iso-8859-1&delete=true")
    .process(new ProcessorName())
    .pollEnrich().simple("${property.URI_FILE}", String.class).aggregationStrategy(new Estrategia()).timeout(10000).aggregateOnException(true)
    .choice()
        .when(simple("${property.result} == 'OK'"))
            .to(URI_OUTPUT)
    .endChoice();
```

This route takes a file from PATH_INPUT, compare it with the file URI_FILE (I generate URI_FILE property in ProccessorName()) and if URI_FILE body contains a specific data, then the result is "OK" and send it to URI_OUTPUT (activeMQ).

This works ok, but later I noticed that this generated a lot of waiting threads, one for each exchange.

[image]

I don't know why is this happening. I have tried with a ConsumerTemplate and the results are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is expected if you generate a unique URI per endpoint you poll. I assume you generate a dynamic fileName which you specify in that URI, and that you see a thread per endpoint?

I have logged a ticket to make this easier in the future
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11250

If you just want to set the message body to a specify file name, then the fastest and easiest is to use setBody as a `java.io.File` type:

```
.setBody(simple("${property.URI_FILE}", java.io.File))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same trouble and faced memory leak. As a workaround, I implemented my own 'org.apache.camel.spi.PollingConsumerPollStrategy' which catches the Consumer when it is begun (by pollEnrich) and sends it to a bean that shall hold all of these consumers in a Map.

Then, I added a timer-route only to trigger a purge action onto the Map that checks if a given time limit has been reached for each of them. If so, it stops the Consumer (leading to interrupt its related thread) and then removes it from the Map.

Like this:

```
    from("direct://foo")
        .to("an endpoint that returns the file name")
        .pollEnrich()
            .simple("file://{{app.runtime.draft.path}}"
                    + "?fileName=${body}"
                    + "&recursive=true"
                    + "&delete=true"
                    + "&pollStrategy=#myFilePollingStrategy" // my poll strategy
                    + "&maxMessagesPerPoll=1")
            .timeout(6 * 1000L)
        .end()
        .to("direct://a")
        .to("direct://b")
        .to("direct://c")
    .end();

    from("timer://file-consumer-purge?period=5s")
        .bean(fileConsumerController, "purge")
    .end();

@Component
public class FileConsumerController {

    private Map<Consumer, Long> mapConsumers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static final long LIMIT = 25 * 1000L; // 25 seconds

    public void hold(Consumer consumer) {
        mapConsumers.put(consumer, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public void purge() {
        mapConsumers.forEach((consumer, startTime) -> {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > LIMIT) {
                try {
                    consumer.stop();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    mapConsumers.remove(consumer);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

@Component
public class MyFilePollingStrategy extends DefaultPollingConsumerPollStrategy {

    @Autowired
    FileConsumerController fileConsumerController;

    @Override
    public boolean begin(Consumer consumer, Endpoint endpoint) {
        fileConsumerController.hold(consumer);
        return super.begin(consumer, endpoint);
    }

}
```

- Notes:

  1. I monitored the behavior through jconsole;
  2. I've only overwritten the `begin()` method and haven't tested the effects over unexpected / error scenarios.

Hope this helps for now, and may the component be evolved. :)